# Python/SWIG TypeError

Tags: c++, python, swig

I've created a simple SWIG helper function to deal with the pointers returned from the C++ code I've wrapped:

```
//in module foo:
%inline %{
  double getPtrVal(double *ptr, int i) {
    return (double) ptr[i];
  }
%}
```

This worked fine until I tried something like:

```
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(n):
    val = foo.getPtrVal(ptrs, i)
```

at which point Python returned with a TypeError, complaining that `n` wasn't an integer:

```
  for i in range(n):
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I assure you that `n` is, in fact, an integer (`type(n)` consistently returns `<type 'int'>`). Thus, I believe the problem lies somehow in the SWIG function. The strange thing is that `foo.getPtrVal(ptrs, i)` is called `n` times without issue, then, immediately after exiting the inner loop over `j` for the first time, the error is thrown. Any ideas? I could post further code segments if it would clarify parts. Thanks!

Comment: The first line of your Python code is missing a colon at the end, by the way. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Original code did include the colon, just missed it in the post.

Comment: "I could post further code segments if it would clarify parts." -- If the code you have posted is not the code you are running then it's a dishonest question. Try compiling and running just the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into a similar problem before. If some part of your SWIG C wrapper code is not properly cleaning up Python's internal exception state, then the very next builtin call capable of raising an exception in your Python code will appear to be the source of the exception.

`range` can raise exceptions, so Python inspects its internal exception state after calling it, sees the exception left over from your SWIG C wrapper code, and assumes that it must have come from `range`.

When I couldn't fix such a problem I used this ugly workaround to clear the internal exception state:

```
try:
        sys.stdout.write("") # any call capable of raising an exception will do
except:
        pass
```

The proper way might be with an `%exception` directive; see the [SWIG manual](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn44). But you need to figure out which call is causing the exception, first.

Comment: Interesting, many thanks! I'll give it a go, or perhaps just convert to pure Python. We'll see how the speed of NumPy compares to C++'s Eigen.

Answer (score 0):

Did actual code have missing colon?